# Ambiguity: There is "no question"

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation

> There should be **no question** in the mind of any student who has shown any interest in the subjects he is learning that his mastery of any subject is painstaking and time-consuming.

This is an example sentence from my workbook. I think "there is no question" could have opposite meanings depending on the context. How would you interpret this sentence, 1a or 1b？

1a. Those students believe mastery of a subject is painstaking...
1b.  Those students believe it is **impossible** that mastery of a subject is painstaking...

**EDIT:**  To provide more Information

As shown in the dictionary, "question" could mean both "doubt" or "possibility":

> 3 [noncount] a : doubt or uncertainty about something
> There was little question of her being able to do the work.
> 4 [noncount] : the possibility or chance of something happening or of someone doing something
> There was no question of him forgetting about what happened.
> Webster dictionary:
> https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "question" something is to call it into doubt. If there is "no question in one's mind that X", then there is no doubt that X, so it is certainly true. Therefore, your sentence means (with some re-ordering of words):

> In the mind of any student who has shown any interest in the subjects he is learning, **it is certainly true** that his mastery of any subject is painstaking and time-consuming.

This is similar to your 1a and opposite to your 1b.

Comment: Thank you. But as shown in the dictionary, "question" could mean both "doubt" or "possibility". The space here is too small, so I edited my question.

Comment: @ForOU Thank you for editing the question; it's helpful. I edited my answer a little as a result. "No question" means "no doubt", and that can sometimes mean "no possibility". For example: "There's no question of the sun rising in the west tomorrow. It's simply not going to happen." However, that meaning is not typical when we say "no question in one's mind that . . .".

Answer (score 0):

I upvoted MarcinManhattan and I think that's a good answer.

I would just add, if your dictionary said "question" can mean "possibility", it does not mean it in the sense that you are interpreting it. If you say, "I question if X is true", you mean that you doubt that it is true. In a sense you could say that you are discussing the possibility that it is true, but you are phrasing it in a negative way. To question something does not mean you are suggesting that it is true. Just the opposite, it means that you are suggesting that it is false.